# How do I determine my highest obtained rank for the current season in Heroes of the Storm?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

Heroes of the Storm has two [ranked play modes](http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/game/ranked-play/): Hero League and Team League. Depending on how well you do in a season you earn rewards. Presently, players are competing for [2017 Ranked Season 1 Rewards](http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/blog/20562668/2017-ranked-season-1-rewards-3-9-2017). Your peak rank determines what rewards you receive.

While I have finished my placements for both modes in Team League I believe I have fluctuated between two different tiers, but want to be sure. Is there a way to determine my peak rank prior to the season changing over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this information in the Statistics-Tab in your profile. Just select a season and then you can find your highest ranks in the bottom right corner.

[image]